# Fell topology: closure operator

Tags: representation-theory

I have spent a bit of time getting used to the Fell topology on the unitary dual. My main reference as an introduction is P. Eymard: Moyennes invariantes et représentations unitaires. I quickly outline the definition of the Fell topology introduced there and then describe my problem.

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group, $\hat{G}$ shall denote the set obtained by taking equivalence classes of topologically irreducible unitary representations of $G$, where $(\pi:G\to U(\mathcal{H}_{\pi}),\mathcal{H}_{\pi})$ and $(\rho:G\to U(\mathcal{H}_{\rho}),\mathcal{H}_{\rho})$ are equivalent if there exists an isomorphism $\Phi:\mathcal{H}_{\pi}\to\mathcal{H}_{\rho}$ of topological vector spaces such that:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{H}_{\pi} @>{\Phi}>> \mathcal{H}_{\rho}\\
@V{\pi(g)}VV @VV{\rho(g)}V \\
\mathcal{H}_{\pi} @>>{\Phi}> \mathcal{H}_{\rho}
\end{CD}\quad\forall g\in G$$

> **Question 0:** Is this the correct equivalence relation? The professor of mine from whom I first learnt about representation theory used this definition. I have seen requirements that $\Phi$ be an isometry as well. But I think it all works out the same using his definition of equivalence once I have checked that such an isomorphism introduces an equivalent inner product.

Given an equivalence class $\pi\in\hat{G}$, we denote by $PD(\pi)$ the set of (positive definite, continuous) functions $\left\{g\mapsto\langle\pi(g)\xi,\xi\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_{\pi}};\xi\in\mathcal{H}_{\pi}\setminus\{0\}\right\}$ and for $S\subseteq\hat{G}$, we say that $\pi\precsim S$ if for all $\phi\in PD(\pi)$, for all $K\subseteq G$ compact and for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $F\subseteq\cup_{\rho\in S}PD(\rho)$ finite such that:
$$\lVert\phi-\sum_{\psi\in F}\psi\rVert_{K,\infty}:=\sup_{g\in K}\lvert\phi(g)-\sum_{\psi\in F}\psi(g)\rvert<\epsilon$$

Pierre Eymard defines $\overline{\cdot}:\mathfrak{P}(\hat{G})\to\mathfrak{P}(\hat{G})$ by:
$$\overline{S}:=\{\pi\in\hat{G};\pi\precsim S\}$$
and then says that $\overline{S}$ is the closure of $S$ in $\hat{G}$. So I tried to check the Kuratowski axioms:

1. $\overline{\emptyset}=\emptyset$
2. $S\subseteq\overline{S}$ for all $S\in\mathfrak{P}(\hat{G})$
3. $\overline{\overline{S}}=\overline{S}$ for all $S\in\mathfrak{P}(\hat{G})$
4. $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$ for all $A,B\in\mathfrak{P}(\hat{G})$

The first three conditions are fine quite immediately except for the third being a bit tedious on notation. With respect to the fourth, $\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$ ought to be obvious as:
$$\pi\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}\Leftrightarrow\pi\in\overline{A}\lor\pi\in\overline{B}\Leftrightarrow\pi\precsim A\lor\pi\precsim B\Rightarrow\pi\precsim A\cup B$$
However I have no idea why the converse inclusion should hold.

> **Question:** Can you give me a hint on why the converse inclusion holds?

**Update 02/12/2014:** I have reduced the discussion to the following situation: Let $PD(S):=\cup_{\rho\in S}PD(\rho)$ for any subset $S\subseteq\hat{G}$. I have found a vector $\xi\in V_{\pi}\setminus\{0\}$, $K_{A},K_{B}\subseteq G$ compact and $\epsilon_{0}>0$ such that for all $F_{A}\subseteq PD(A)$ and $F_{B}\subseteq PD(B)$ finte holds:
$$\begin{align}
\lVert\langle\pi(\cdot)\xi,\xi\rangle-\sum_{\chi\in F_{A}}\chi\rVert_{K_{A},\infty}\geq&\epsilon_{0}\\
\lVert\langle\pi(\cdot)\xi,\xi\rangle-\sum_{\chi\in F_{B}}\chi\rVert_{K_{B},\infty}\geq&\epsilon_{0}
\end{align}$$
and hence in particular on $K=K_{A}\cup K_{B}$ we can approximate the positive definite function very badly by positive definite functions from either set.

> **Question:** can we show that $\phi_{0}(\cdot):=\langle\pi(\cdot)\xi,\xi\rangle$ can not be approximated uniformly on compacta by finite sums of elements in $PD(A)\cup PD(B)$?

If we can, then we are done. I have tried toying around with the reverse triangle inequality, which yields $\lVert\sum_{\chi\in F_{x}}\chi\rVert_{K_{x},\infty}\geq \delta$, where $x\in\{A,B\}$ and $F_{A}\subseteq PD(A)$, $F_{B}\subseteq PD(B)$ finite, $\epsilon>2\delta>0$ such that: $$\lVert\phi_{0}-\sum_{\chi\in F_{A}\cup F_{B}}\chi\rVert_{K,\infty}<\delta$$
But I did not manage to conclude from this -- I have not yet tried my last comment though. I will do so now.

Comment: The following might be useful: Assume that $\pi\in\hat{G}$, $S\subseteq{\hat{G}}$. The following are equivalent:
**1.** $\pi\precsim S$
**2.** $\forall\phi\in PD(\pi)$, $\forall K\subseteq G$ compact, $\forall\epsilon>0$ there is $\psi\in\cup_{\rho\in S}PD(\rho)$ such that: $$\lVert\phi-\psi\rVert_{K,\infty}<\epsilon$$
This automatically implies that each element in $PD(\pi)$ can be approximated uniformly on compacta by elements in $PD(A)$ or $PD(B)$. Now I have to show: if either of the sets has been ruled out, the other is feasible for all elements in $PD(\pi)$. I am still stuck here though.